# Decategorize certain formatted cells as values in an additional column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have excel data in one column, so I need to decategorize certain formatted cells as values in additional column, how can I do this?

You may see raw column include data of universities, faculties and programs. So I need to distract faculties and universities in different columns, knowing that university and faculty data are formatted differently from other data.

[image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/hithMCZ1Tay9OYy6IXuaiA.png]

Comment: Have you written any code? What you want would need some VBA coding to iterate down column "Raw Data" and depending on the values copy to the appropriate column.

Comment: No I didnt and dont know where to start from

Comment: You'll want to do some searches on this site to figure it out. I'll assume you don't know how to add a vba module, so I'll give that much. Click "View" on the ribbon. Click "Macros" on the right. Type in a name for the macro and then click "Create". That will create a VBA module with a subroutine named after what you entered.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but what will the function code be to achieve the goal above?

Comment: The idea of this site is to first research what you need to do and write some code. If you have code and need help then you'll get help, but first you need to show some effort in solving the problem on your own. HINTS: You'll need to research how to refer to the cells within your worksheet, create a loop (I recommend a "While") to look at each cell in column "A" until a blank is reached and write the if statements to put the values in either column B or column C. You can also set the colors and fonts while setting the values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need VBA? From your sample info, I believe you can use two formulas.

In your column B, starting at `B3`, use:

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,LEN("Faculty"))="Faculty",A3,B2)
```

And in `C2`, use:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,LEN("University"))="University",A2,C1)
```

and drag both down.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the above formulas, but I guess its a 3 level data structure which need to be extracted from one raw column into 3 individual ones, All universities are in bold+red, all faculties are in bold+black, and programs in normal fort

https://image.prntscr.com/image/mw-M_KfpQvaOQe9P0EAuug.png